# Get session ID based on session name

Tags: php, session

In one script, I included the following script:

```
session_name('SESSION1');
session_start();
//bla bla bla
```

In another script which is using another session (not named SESSION1), given only the session name used in the first script (SESSION1), how do I get the session ID being used by the first script?

Comment: I think you can find the value of the session within `$_COOKIE['SESSION1']`

Comment: @silkfire is right, the PHP session is stored in the cookie (as SID), so the Session name will be as well I suppose.
Just tried this, the session is indeed named and stored in the cookie.

Comment: I missed the obvious, and was looking for some special PHP function.  Thank you

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario.  No, session_id will return the current session ID.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  Perhaps I wasn't clear in the original post.  The second script is not using the session who's name is SESSION1.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061966/accessing-two-sessions-in-given-php-script for what I was attempting to do. The problem with this solution is I did not wish to use hard coded session IDs.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  My goal is to access data in a session other than the one the given script was originally using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to find the session ID within the cookie:

```
$_COOKIE['SESSION1']
```

Comment: Two easy!  Outside of the scope of my original question, but why would one ever use `session_name()`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  Not if the second script is using a different session_name.